# Timestamp with timezone in HSQLDB

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb, dbunit

My project is using postgres and there are also some in memory tests with hsqldb (2.4.1)

The Client entity has this field:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(updatable = false)
private Date creationDate;
```

Where Date is the java.util.Date

The table is created using "timestamp with timezone"

```
CREATE TABLE client (
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  creationdate timestamp with time zone,
  ...)
```

When I am running the tests, dbunit is loading a file with data and i get this error:

```
2018-08-21 09:39:03,194 [warn] o.d.u.SQLHelper - CLIENT.CREATIONDATE data type (2014, 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE') not recognized and will be ignored. See FAQ for more information.
```

So I figured that I should extend HSQLDialect to be able to support it. However I can't figure out how, is it registerColumnType() or registerHibernateType() what I need? Or maybe some casting instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a dbUnit class (perhaps obfuscated by the logging framework to "o.d.u.SQLHelper") emitting that warning message.  It means that the specified data type is not supported by dbUnit.

### TL;DR

Please create an enhancement request to support this SQL Standard data type:
https://sourceforge.net/p/dbunit/feature-requests/

Having dbUnit support this data type will happen much faster if you implement it with tests and create a merge request or attach a patch.

### Details

The message says "See FAQ", and the FAQ page has info on the issue:
http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#typenotrecognized

Click the "replace the default data type factory" link to this FAQ entry:
http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#typefactory

It shows using a database-specific data type factory.
Your database is HSQLDB, so, as it mentions, find its class in the "org.dbunit.ext.hsqldb" subpackage: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/xref/org/dbunit/ext/hsqldb/HsqldbDataTypeFactory.html.

Configure dbUnit to use it following the example.
Or, depending on your setup (e.g. using Spring?  Which TestCase?), this is a helpful example and another approach (this example is my typical setup):
http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/testcases/PrepAndExpectedTestCase.html#Configuration_Example_Using_Spring

However, reviewing HsqldbDataTypeFactory's source shows that data type not supported in it:
http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/xref/org/dbunit/ext/hsqldb/HsqldbDataTypeFactory.html

or its parent:
http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/xref/org/dbunit/dataset/datatype/DefaultDataTypeFactory.html

The parent, DefaultDataTypeFactory, on line 71 delegates to DataType:
http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/xref/org/dbunit/dataset/datatype/DataType.html

DataType defines the supported data types using the Java API Types class:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html

Searching the Types page for "timestamp with timezone" finds:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE

We see that it was added in Java 8.

Searching DataType for Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE does not find support for "timestamp with timezone".  This is how we know it is missing.

Comment: All correct. JDBC standard support for TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is available in HSQLDB version 2.4.0 and later. The Java type is `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. Some other `java.time` package classes are also supported. So DbUnit should check for HSQLDB version.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeff for the detailed answer, i figured it out eventually, i was indeed confused and looking for an hsqldb solution to it, this is why i also couldn't find the faq.

Comment: @kopelitsa I'm wondering how you fixed and/or what your next steps are to fix?